# AngularJS for website like ebay

Tags: jquery, angularjs, rest, routes, pjax

is angular recommended for websites like ebay, website for product ads..
Some of features:

- categories list
- ads list(for categories)
- login
- signup
- my products
- add/change/delete product
- profile settings

I need good routing, need fast loading, not whole content..
To use angular, of jquery pjax, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angularjs is just for the frontend.To create every one thing on your list you need first to create them on your server side and use angular to fetch them on your frontend.